# Why doesn't the Timer Start in Program?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple C# program (done in MS visual Studio 2010).
It is a windows form with a single button on it. As you can see its just a simple program but Im stuck on it.
I am trying to understand C# timers and global variables in C#.

I wanted it  to do the following,  when the button is pressed
a message box appears (every second) displaying the number 
of seconds since the button was pressed. 
It supposed to working by setting a variable `starttimer` to true (in one function) and in another function when that `starttimer` equals true is detected it shows the time in seconds in the message box.

However it it doesn't seem to detect that `starttimer` equals true in the other function. The purpose of the **starttimer** variable is to detect the button press for using to start showing the message box every second.

So what the easiest way to fix this program?

PS When the program is run without the code for `starttimer` it does show the message box every second (when the program is started).

A picture of the program windows form is shown -as you can see it really simple-just one button.

```
namespace timerprogram
{
    public partial class doeverysecond : Form
    {
        int thetimeinsecs  = 0; 
        bool starttimer = false;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }    

        private void customfn(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (starttimer == true)
            {
                thetimeinsecs = thetimeinsecs + 1;
                MessageBox.Show(thetimeinsecs.ToString());
            }
        }

        public doeverysecond()
        {
            {            
                {   
                    System.Timers.Timer mytimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    mytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(customfn);
                    mytimer.Interval = 1000;
                    mytimer.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            starttimer = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You never call doeverysecond

Comment: It's C#, not "C Sharp"

Comment: And you wouldn't want to create a new timer each time, the "mytimer" should be moved out to the class.

Comment: You should be using the WinForms timer.  You have to declare the timer at the form scope level or else the garbage collector can't dispose of it.  Where's your InitializeComponent call?

Comment: actually the message box shows every second witthout the condition -so it cant be that-can it derek?

Comment: @Derek doeverysecond is the constructor.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because of the excessive whitespace.  Could you please reformat it with the excessive whitespace?  Now, for you problem, is the MessageBox not showing at all?  Your form's constructor has two sets of unneeded curly braces.  Since the timer variable is being created inside the constructor, it may be getting garbage collected too soon.  Try making the `mytimer` variable global as well.

Comment: Format your code, question ... basically everything. This question is unreadable in it's current state.

Comment: **Maybe** you should mark your `starttimer` with a `volatile` keyword? Sometimes optimizations mess up with flags used in a loop.

Comment: Have you put any breakpoints?  Do you hit the button click code? Do you hit breakpoints in the customfn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers can be a bit weird, but it looks like your main issue is that `mytimer` is within a method scope, meaning that when that method ends, `mytimer` is cleaned up by the garbage collector and it stops running. This happens because when the method ends, there is no way to access `mytimer` again from elsewhere in the code. To save on memory, .NET cleans up after you, but in this particular case it's not smart enough to know that you are actually still using the timer.

The solution is quite simple, put `mytimer` at the class level. You can also get rid of the `starttimer` bool, as now you can check the timer itself to see if it's running.

You could do something like:

```
namespace timerprogram
{
    public partial class doeverysecond : Form
    {
        //Timer is class level, so it sticks around and can be called from
        //multiple methods
        System.Timers.Timer mytimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        int thetimeinsecs = 0; 

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Setup the timer, but don't start it
            mytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(customfn);
            mytimer.Interval = 1000;
        }    

        private void customfn(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //We can check the timer itself to see if it's running!
            if (mytimer.Enabled)
            {
                thetimeinsecs = thetimeinsecs + 1;
                MessageBox.Show(thetimeinsecs.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Start the timer!
            mytimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and with regards to that whole 'scope' thing. In C#, a scope is basically something in between a { and a }. In methods and normal code, variables created inside a scope cannot be seen by code outside the scope. That's why you get a compiler error if you do something like:

```
if(something)
{
    int x = 5;
}
x = x + 5; //x doesn't exist here! It disappears at }
```

You can access things from outside a scope inside a scope though, so

```
int x = 0;
if(something)
{
    x = 5; //x exists in an outside scope
}
x = x + 5; //This is fine
```

Anything at the class scope can be seen by all methods inside a class, which is why the timer now sticks around. Class scope is slighty different though, in that you can see things in other classes if they have public before them. The same goes for methods (Note that all your methods have 'private', so outside classes can't call them. Change them to public and they can!)

Comment: Actually, as soon as the event is registered. The timer will remain in the memory until either the enemy is unregistered or the program is ended. The garbage collector will not touch the timer as long the event is registered

Comment: I didnt use Form1_load in my original program.  Form1_load - from your code -it gets called automatically  for as long program is running onscreen-is that right? And Form1_load doesnt just get called once at the beginning when the form loads into the screen/graphics memory

Answer (score 2):

> So what the easiest way to fix this program?

Actually it would be to hit the button, so that the variable `starttimer` is set to `true` and you will be able to see the `MessageBox`every second. You program works!

Beside that it would be good to bring more structure into your program, by having a method that starts the timer with a button click:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!mytimer.Enabled) // this will prevent a double start
        {
            starttimer = true;
            mytimer.Start();
        }
    }
```

The constructor should get rid of the timer start line:

```
public doeverysecond()
{
    {   
        System.Timers.Timer mytimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        mytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(customfn);
        mytimer.Interval = 1000;
    }
 }
```

Division of responsibilities is important here. The constructor is for initialisation of variables. So this is his job. The Button starts the timer.

The if-clause to check `if (starttimer == true)` is actually not necessary, since you never call this method from somewhere else in your code.

And setting the boolean variable to true does **not** start the timer. It is only a flag!

Comment: Actually it would be to hit the button, so that the variable starttimer is set to true and you will be able to see the MessageBoxevery second. You program works! .-I still havent got it to work-I must be missing something simple

Comment: your right startimer could have had a better name -its purpose is to show the timer on the screen- a flag to detect the button press

Comment: What version of C Sharp you using? 2010?

Comment: I am using VS 2013, and 2015. I cannot imagine that they changed the workings of a timer between the versions. Either you set the variable to `true` somewhere else in the code (a part you haven't posted), or you simply pressed the button. I cannot imagine that the if-clause is not working

Answer (score -2):

Need to enable the timer.

```
myTimer.Enabled = true
```

Comment: No. `Start()` will enable the timer.

Comment: The OP called `mytimer.Start();` in the constructor which enables the timer.